# How to create a framework compatible with different java versions?

Tags: java, architecture, frameworks, application-design

Let's say I want to create a standard project implementation, so I'm going to create a framework reusable by next projects to be developed.

Imagine there is a constraint on java version:

- Project A has to use java 8,
- Project B has to use java 17,
- Project C has to use java 21.

What are the rules that need to be followed in order to be able to build a framework that should work with multiple java version?

idk, something like

> creating the framework with the lowest java version, minimize the dependencies on newer language features or APIs that may not be available in older Java versions.

I did not find much on that, hope it's not a stupid question, any good resources to understand more about creating generic frameworks that can be easily reused will be really appreciated!

Comment: That's really it.  There's not a lot more to be said.

Comment: Note: some standard APIs have been removed from Java starting with Java 9 (e.g. `LogManager.addPropertyChangeListener()`) -- each version comes with a Migration Guide that list these - see the [Migration Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/migrate/removed-apis.html#GUID-FAD4E80D-64BA-42AC-A682-38D06EE61AC6) for Java 21

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> creating the framework with the lowest java version, minimize the dependencies on newer language features or APIs that may not be available in older Java versions.

Well, yes. That's stating the obvious: If the library has to work with a project that is on java 8, obviously that library cannot use java9+ in any way: No java9+ features (no `--source 9` / `--release 9`), no java9+ class files (`--target 9` / `--release 9`), no use of any API whose `@since` flag in its java doc reads java9 or higher, and no dependency on any library which isn't itself compatible with java8 and below.

Starting in.. java9? It's been in there for a while, but, jars can ship with multiple copies of the same class file, tailored to each JDK release. This is called the [Multi-release JAR](https://nipafx.dev/multi-release-jars-multiple-java-versions/) system. This feature is extremely rarely used, and using this feature is a maintenance nightmare (goooood luck testing all this; the usual java tooling (maven, gradle, junit, you name it) aren't designed to let you test the same code on many different JDK releases), and generally there's no point to it: Either the API in the java version you can't use because it is too recent is a convenience, and there is no benefit making a version that does not use it, as well as one that does use it - just build the one that does not. Or, it's a feature that doesn't exist until then (say, new file API to, say, make a hard link, something introduced in `java.nio.file` API that simply wasn't available in the old `java.io` package), and thus, you **cannot** make a library that 'works' on the java release that doesn't ship with it.

Note that java 8 has been end of lifed.

Comment: "jars can ship with multiple copies of the same class file, tailored to each JDK release" TIL, but I think I won't worry too much about remembering :-)

Comment: Regarding "jars can ship with multiple copies of the same class file", can you link to some documentation on that? I have never heard of that feature. (Maybe [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/java-classloader-handling) is discussing that feature?)

Comment: Regarding Java 8 being end-of-lifed, I have been confused about that. It seems some JDK vendors are continuing to publish publicly available updates to Java 8. For example [Adoptium on 2024-01-24](https://adoptium.net/temurin/releases/?version=8) with 8.0.402+6.

Comment: @BasilBourque I have added a link to a tutorial that explains how to use/make MR-JARs. It took me 15 minutes to find it and some really creative web search queries to even find it. That should be ample proof __nobody__ uses this frankly befuddling concept. One of the great many duds in the jigsaw spec, I guess.

Comment: @tgdavies I made a link for you in case you want to renege on your 'eh, fun but nah' conclusion. But, you might wanna stick to it: I spent 20 minutes searching the web just to find the official name of this feature let alone a guide on how to make/use these. I wouldn't even be surprised if literally ZERO projects on all of mavencentral are an MR-jar.